# PowerMockito private method doThrow stubbing

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

```
private int privateMethod(Object o, boolean b) throws Exception
```

--

```
PowerMockito.doThrow(new Throwable("Just a throwable")).when(spy, "privateMethod", Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());
```

--

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected
```

I already tried switching the any() to anyObject() etc.
But i am getting the stubbing problem...

Where is the error?

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The `org.mockito.Matchers.anyBoolean` matcher worked for me.

`anyObject` and `any` didn't match against primitives.

Comment: tried it with anyObject() and anyBoolean(), also tried the real object and false, but always the same error